# jquery dropdown onclick select nearest radio

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have a list of items that can have values selected from a dropdown or entered free text. I'd like to have a radio button automatically selected beside either the dropdown or text box when they're clicked on.

I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".click_radio").click(function() {  
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
  });
</script>

<html>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ord_55" value="yes" /> Sodium Chloride </td>
      <td><input type="RADIO" name="dose" value="drop"/> &nbsp;
        <select id="drop_dose_1" name="nsbolus_drop_dose" class="click_radio">
          <option></option>
          <option>250</option>
          <option>500</option>
          <option>1000</option>
        </select> ml
      </td>
      <td><input type="RADIO" name="dose" value="text"/> &nbsp; 
        <input type="text" size="4" id="text_dose_1" name="nsbolus_text_dose" value="" class="click_radio"/> ml
      </td>
      <td><select name="nsbolus_pri">
          <option>STAT</option>
          <option>NEXT SCH</option>
          <option>1ST DOSE TODAY</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

I could trigger it directly but I really want a universal script that will work for any of the dozens of similar items that follow this one.

thanks!

**Edit**
I should also mention I'm on JQuery 1.9.1

Comment: I think you need to handle `change` event of `select` element. This event is fired when select selection changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.click_radio').on('click change', function(){
    $(this).prev('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

This uses [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and will work for as many elements as you need as long as the radio input is *immediately* before the element with the `.click_radio` class.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/tv8SR/4/

Comment: That's exactly the functionality I want, but I'm still using 1.9.1 any way to make it work without going up?

Comment: @GroundZero - I just had to change the input type from `RADIO` to `radio` to get it to work. Older versions of jquery must be case sensitive when selecting by attribute name. Just check my updated fiddle link for the working version.

Answer (score 1):

While you have good answers already I thought I would add in mine as the current answers fail to address the select box that you have.

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CBRc4/1/

The changes I made are quite simple, I made the function reusable and listen for two types of events. For selecting and checking the correct radio I simply use `.siblings(selector)`.

Here is the code from the fiddle:

```
var eventHandler = function() {
  $(this).siblings('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
};

$(function() {
  $(".click_radio").on({
    click: eventHandler,
    change: eventHandler
  });
});
```

You can see I reuse the same handler for both click and change to ensure the same functionality.

EDIT: Working example with jQuery 1.9.1 here http://jsfiddle.net/CBRc4/2/

A note about why the original example doesn't work in jQuery in 1.9.1 is the type declaration `type="RADIO"` and you querying for `input[type=radio]`. If you change either to match then it will successfully perform the selection (most likely a change regarding the Sizzle selector engine). But the example works find in 1.9.1 after the change is made and I've linked to a working 1.9.1 fiddle.

Comment: That's a great solution, can it be adapted for JQuery 1.9.1?

Comment: @GroundZero Yes it can, the change necessary is to specify your type and query for the type in the same case (i.e. `type="RADIO"` and `input[type=RADIO]`). Given that HTML should be all lowercase `type="radio"` is the path that I selected to go to make the example work with 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the elements are both within the same container you can use [siblings([selector])](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).  Optionally, you could provide the selector in the rel attribute of the input and then onclick, use the rel as the selector to trigger or set the appropriate other element.

```
$("text_dose_1").on('click', function() { this.siblings('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', 'checked'); });
```

And as long as the radio buttons are in a group the others should be unchecked accordingly.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7 and forward you should use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`